# Adding to ListView from and EditView input

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

I have seen these questions and tried all the answers.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I have all the declarations on top, then I have my arrayadapter, then I have my enter button with onClick but when I try to input anything as soon as I click the button it crashes.

**Code:**

```
    //create a list
    final ListView shotList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shotList);
    String[] values = new String[] { "6/10/13 (Attack)", "4/25/13 (Dr. Apt.)", "3/4/13 (Attack)" };
    Button enterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enterButt);
    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterText);
    final String input = editText.getText().toString();

     final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
          list.add(values[i]);
        }

        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        shotList.setAdapter(adapter);

      //add data to list via enter button

        enterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        { 
            public void onClick(View v)
            {                   
                    list.add(input);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //list.add(new String(editText.getText().toString()));
            }
        });
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////    

//array adapter
private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      String item = getItem(position);
      return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return true;
    }


       }
      }
```

**Logcat:**

```
06-28 19:24:52.149: D/AndroidRuntime(29515): Shutting down VM
06-28 19:24:52.149: W/dalvikvm(29515): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at com.asthmaassistant.ShotActivity$StableArrayAdapter.getItemId(ShotActivity.java:104)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2180)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-28 19:24:52.239: E/AndroidRuntime(29515):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 19:24:55.409: I/Process(29515): Sending signal. PID: 29515 SIG: 9
06-28 19:24:57.329: E/Trace(29543): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-28 19:24:58.129: D/dalvikvm(29543): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 8% free 2498K/2692K, paused 77ms, total 82ms
06-28 19:24:58.161: I/dalvikvm-heap(29543): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.470MB for 960016-byte allocation
06-28 19:24:58.309: D/dalvikvm(29543): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3433K/3632K, paused 146ms, total 146ms
06-28 19:24:58.439: D/dalvikvm(29543): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 3433K/3632K, paused 16ms+19ms, total 132ms
06-28 19:24:59.479: I/Choreographer(29543): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-28 19:24:59.609: D/gralloc_goldfish(29543): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

LOGCAT:
06-30 19:25:34.192: E/AndroidRuntime(9478): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131230742, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.asthmaassistant.StableArrayAdapter)]

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: What is line 104 of ShotActivity.java?

Comment: I don't have a line 104

Answer (score 0):

You "input" variable is null when you are clicking the button , you are storing data into that variable inside onCreate , actually you should do it inside onClick method .

put your

```
String input = editText.getText().toString();
```

code inside onClick method.

I think the problem is the way how you store the ids , you have to pass the newly added items id to your adapter .You get ids only when constructor of your adapter gets called .

You are getting null pointer because after adding new item , you constructor is not being called and hence id for newly added item could not be found.

Comment: I put it inside and the app still crashes when I press the button to add the text

Comment: I understand exactly what your saying...  Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: I think my null pointer is in the line: String input = editText.getText().toString();     Can anyone see if it is or isn't here.  I've been working on it for days.

Comment: Are you calling notifyDataSetChange method from a background thread like AsyncTask or using a regular Thread ?

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    <--thats the only time i call it.

Comment: I have been back and forth on this using methods which worked for a lot of other people on this site.  Nothing works and I can't see where my npe is coming from.

Comment: first of all remove final keyword from all the views because you are using them again and again in your activity and they are not constant.
May be that is the reason you are getting NPE.

Comment: I cannot remove it from the arraylist or adapter :    Cannot refer to a non-final variable list inside an inner class defined in a different method.   Tried it without removing those and still npe

Comment: Remove those final variables and make them global at class level .
Like Listview list;
than it will not give that compilation error.
You must have to try this bro.